# Google Analytics - multiple domain and sites

Tags: google-analytics

I have a system that manages about 200 sites. Each has a unique domain name and unique content but all of the urls for the sites are the same, since they use the same template.

I currently have each site with a unique GA account. I would like to also have another GA number where I can aggregate the behavior and traffic from all the sites. Since the url paths are all similar I am thinking the reporting would be nice as a roll up.

The goal is to get total stats and pattern behavior without having to go to 200 different dashboards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of missing the question here. If you're asking if this is possible - yes, it's described in the google analytics documentation (you'll find an example at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#MultipleCommands). You have to be careful that events, custom vars etc. are always pushed to both trackers.

Is it useful ? That depends. Analytics data is useful to the the extent that it's actionable. You're looking (I think) for a report that adds up visits for the same URL but on different domains with different content. I would presume that user behaviour is determined by the content rather than the URL, so personally I would think that kind of report would result in gibberish (data that looks valid but is not actually meaningful) - but then I don't know your reporting requirements, maybe you can eek out some meaning from that.

A "master" account for all domains might be useful if there is something else that the sites have in common - e.g. if you have a common online advertising budget or SEO strategy for all sites and want to optimize that, or if you simply want to see in a nice graphical interface how many users hit your server (if the domains all reside on the same server).

Even then I don't think it's a good idea to lump up all domains - you should rather set a custom filter to include the hostname in the tracked url (http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012243) instead of lumnping all domains together.

At the end of the day you have to ask yourself : "Is there anything I would do different after looking at this report" and if the answer is "no" it's probably wasted effort.

Comment: First thanks for your reply. 
Here is the problem. I can easily answer things like how many hits did we get at one of our property sites. I can not however say how many hits did we get at all of our 200 properties. Other things like, as an organization for all of our property sites how much of our traffic is mobile. The work to answer simple questions like that is basically effort x 200 vs just logging in and looking at the aggregate view.

Comment: See the second part of my answer - if you display the hostname your content reports are somewhat easier to read (although I have to admit that you can simply set the host name as second dimension).